# JScrollPane adjustmentListener and scrollRectToVisible

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar, jviewport

I need to handle event from `JScrollPane` when user scrolls it. In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561246/scroll-event-of-a-jscrollpane) it is suggested to use `addAdjustmentListener` to either `JViewport` or Vertical/HorizontalScrollBar.

Is there any difference, which method should I choose?

I would like also to use `scrollRectToVisible` for the same `JScrollPane`, should I anticipate `AdjustmentListener` working for this method?

Also I wonder whether `scrollRectToVisible` tries to do minimum scrolling to make required rectangular visible or it tries to make it visible in the middle of `JViewport` ?

**UPD:** Requirements:

1) There a JScrollPane with one JPanel which has many JLabel(ImageIcon), so some of them are not visible.

2) When a network event comes I need to show one of JLabel (make it visible) to user. If I is not visible originally then JScrollPane should scroll automatically. That's why I mention `scrollRectToVisible`.

3) Above that JLabel with ImageIcon inside I need to show a message which would explain what has happened to this element. The message currently is implemented as another JLabel with floats thanks to JLayeredPane much higher in hierarchy. The problem now is that if user scrolls JScrollPane that floating JLabel should move accordingly to be on top of correponding JLabel(ImageIcon).

**UDP2: SSCCE**

I have not implemented floating JLabel yet, but already I don't like how label with index 11 reacts to `scrollRectToVisible` since it is half cropped.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JScrollPaneTest {
    protected ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JScrollPaneTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public JScrollPaneTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel ();

                panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel("  | Label" + i + " |  ");
                    panel1.add(label, gbc);
                    labels.add(label);
                }

                panel1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
                        JLabel label = labels.get(11);
                        label.scrollRectToVisible(label.getBounds());
                    }
                });

                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel1) {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(600, 400);
                    }
                };

                pane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("adjustmentValueChanged: " + e);
                    }
                });

                frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: could be depends if JComponent placed into JScrollPane has implemented scrollable

Comment: you really should start thinking in requirements (vs. assumed solutions): what _exactly_ do you want to achieve?

Comment: @kleopatra I have added requirements.

Comment: @mKorbel, nope, it is just JPanel inside JScrollPane.

Comment: ahh ... now it's much clearer :-) I would labelWithIcon.scrollRectToVisible(labelWithIcon.getBounds()) and then adjust the floating message to the new label coordinates (in the coordinates you use in the layeredPane) You might consider a SSCCE so we don't have to start from scratch in trying to help you :-)

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov (especially for future readers) as mentioned (@kleopatra) post an SSCCE, there must be some small mistake returns wrong coordinates :-)

Comment: @mKorbel, SSCCE might come tomorrow. I am still in process of design how I should implement this functionality and many recent questions are related to it. Hopefully, this time coordinates would be okay. `SwingUtilities.convertPoint()` appeared to be extremely useful.

Comment: @mKorbel, still I don't know where to add `AdjustmentListener`

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov derive JScrollBar from JScrollPane, btw did you check linked threads, hmmmm right, SwingUtilities.convertPoint() should be usefull to your previous question here,

Comment: @kleopatra, I have added SSCCE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the answer (code in comments is just ... and noticed I had it wrong in the comment ;-)

The method scrollRectToVisible takes a Rectangle in the coordinate system of the component it is called upon. To scroll a child such that it is completely visible, there are basically two options (use *one* of them):

```
// either call on child with zero offset
child.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(child.getSize());
// or call on child's parent with child bounds
child.getParent().scrollRectToVisible(child.getBounds());
```

Comment: wow, do I really need to call scrollRectToVisible() twice for child and parent?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov - no, it's either one or the other, pick your preference, tried to clarify.

Comment: Yes, it works. But it is at the edge now, how can I show it in the center of JScrollPane if it is feasible?

Comment: you have to do some math :-)